# How to log in after wrongly modifying path

Tags: environment-variables, paths, .profile

I wanted to add a path so that the system could find some manually installed executable. However, instead of typing `PATH=xxx:$PATH;export PATH` at the end of ~/.profile where xxx is the directory in which the executable lies, I wrongly used `PATH=xxx;export PATH`.

After I logged out I was unable to log in the usual way. How can I fix this instead of reinstalling?

Comment: Boot from a live cd and delete the path ?

Comment: But how to get into my ~/.profile to change it from the live cd? Please elaborate.

Comment: Boot from a live cd,open nautilus browser and then open your filesystem(not live session file system).Search for home directory and then user directory.Press **CTRL+H** to view hidden files and then edit your ~/.profile

Comment: You can combine / shorten the line to `export PATH=xxx:$PATH`.

Comment: @lekensteyn What is the syntax if I want to add two paths using (a) my method and also (b) your method, other than repeating a new line?

Comment: @Jasper: Something like `export PATH=/path/to/first:/path/to/second:$PATH`. Note that the folder `~/bin` is added to `$PATH` by default if it exist. (see `~/.profile`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to @João Pinto's answer, you cannot use text editors like gedit or Kate. For the terminal or console, use text-based editors like `nano`.

The full steps needed to make changes to the `~/.profile` file:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a text console
2. Login with your username or password
3. Restore your `$PATH` variable by restoring the environment so you can run `nano` without specifying the full path:

   ```
   . /etc/environment
   ```
4. Edit the `~/.profile` file by running:

   ```
   nano ~/.profile
   ```

   Use Arrow keys, Page up or Page down to move the cursor. As with text editors like Kate, you can use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete text before or after the cursor and insert text by typing it.
5. After making the changes, save the changes and quit the `nano` editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> to answer yes on saving changes. Finally, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the filename.
6. You can now logout from the console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (or by executing `exit`)
7. Switch back to the graphical login by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> if F7 did not work.

If this does not work out-of-the-box for whatever reason, then we can always revert to karthick87's answer which Jasper added as an answer below: using a LiveCD to make changes.

Comment: You saved my day

Answer (score 3):

Changing the profile with PATH=xxx;export PATH will not prevent you from loggin in, at least not from the console. Switch to the text console with: CTL-ALT-F1, login, edit the file with your prefered text editor.

Comment: Note to other users: Although I could log in from the console, I could not fire up any editor to edit the file, so it might be best to boot from the live cd, edit the file and then log in as usual.

Comment: @jasper: that's because your `$PATH` variable got messed up. Instead of running `nano ~/.profile`, you should run `/usr/bin/nano ~/.profile`. Alternatively, you can load the default environment with `. /etc/environment` and run `nano ~/.profile` after.

Comment: @lekensteyn Is it right to say this works only if you have an editor capable of running from the console already installed? Also please add your comment as an answer, thanks!

Comment: @Jasper: I've added a complete answer. Novices should understand it. If not, you're welcome to fix the errors or missing information.

Answer (score 2):

Boot from a live CD and open your filesystem from Nautilus (not file system of live session). Search for the home directory, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view hidden files and then edit `~/.profile`. After that remove the live CD and log in as usual.

<sup>This is essentially karthick87's comment but I could not get him to add his comment as an answer, so I am putting this answer down for other users.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To recover from this issue due to messed up values in `/etc/environment` follow the below steps.

1. `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"`
2. remove the contents you added earlier in `/etc/environment` file as a root user.

Now everything will work fine. I had the same issue and recovered using the above steps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do step 2. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: it's helped, because nano didn't working