# Accidentally changed the Path environment variable while installing java via the terminal

Tags: paths

While following a tutorial from Stack Overflow, I set the Java path as instructed, but in the process I got an error. Now I cannot login, as `usr/bin:/usr` is not found.

Comment: At what moment did you get this error ? Can you show what happened in your terminal

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19697/how-to-log-in-after-wrongly-modifying-path

Answer (score 0):

A quick search will find existing answers like this one: [how-to-restore-path-environment-variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291808/how-to-restore-path-environment-variable) and many more.

There are a few options... you can boot to single user, passwordless login (if you have physical access) and then restore:

```
/etc/environment:PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
/etc/login.defs:ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
/etc/login.defs:ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

etc. for all users, or if you only wiped your local user, then consider restoring settings via (on Ubuntu 18.04):

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile /home/<user>/
```

If you only have remote access, you can login as another user, and then restore.