# Reset System Wide PATH variable

Tags: login

I added a line to /etc/environment in order get an additional directory in my system wide PATH variable. I'm now stuck in a login loop.

I can access the shell and modify the PATH variable but Ubuntu freezes when I exit the shell and the PATH variable is reset on reboot.

Any tips on how to get out of this?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to restore /etc/environment to its previous contents when you access the shell.

Comment: Use a live USB, navigate to the file and change the line.

Comment: Thanks both! Will try these two. Eduardo, do  you know of any good ways to reset /etc/environment?    I've seen this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19697/how-to-log-in-after-wrongly-modifying-path but can't manage to find a way to reset to previous values